# In DolphinDB, why can't controller node find agent node?

Tags: database, cluster-computing, dolphindb

I'm configuring a  multi-physical node cluster deployment. 
1. The controller node is on linux debian of Oracle virtual machine( bridge mode) 
2. The agent node and data nodes are on the windows of the host machine.
3. Agent node and controller node can ping each other, but why can't the controller node find the agent node?

Agent node log::  HeartBeatsSender exception: Failed to read response header from the socket with IO error type
Agent node log:: Failed to enable TCP_NODELAY with error code 10038

data node log:  AsynchronousRemoteExecutor::closeConnection to master #10 numConnections=0 Failed to connect
data node log: : close connection to master #10 with error: Failed to connect

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why not deploy DolphinDB on linux os. there is no such case for deploying across different os.